# Magento 2 Form Field Array (Advance system configuration option)

Tags: magento2

Recently I worked on advance system config form field in Magento 2. I checked Braintree payment method for reference.

When I saved a value, it showing following error:

> Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Notice: Array to
>   string conversion in
>   E:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\Magento\Config\Model\Resource\Config\Data.php
>   on line 38

After print `$object->getValue()` array is printed with error:

[image: screenshot 1]

and

[image: screenshot 2]

(click screenshots to enlarge)

Answer (score 1):

Add backend model for this config path. Something like

```
<backend_model>NameSpace\Module\Model\Backend\Config</backend_model>
```

And backend model class looks like

```
namespace NameSpace\Module\Model\Backend
class Config  extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $data = $this->getValue();
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $this->setValue(implode(',', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 serialize values are not directly saved in database it's using some encryption method to store serialize values. After some r & d I found these two methods in Magento 2 to convert serialize and store in db:

```
   protected function encodeArrayFieldValue(array $value)
```

and:

```
   protected function decodeArrayFieldValue(array $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a backend_model for your field in the xml. If you don't have any special needs you can use the `ArraySerialized` model:

```
<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
```